# Why can't I install WebStorm on Linux Fedora 27?

Tags: linux, webstorm, fedora

I want to install WebStorm on Fedora 27. I start `./webstorm.sh` but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

```
Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

Comment: TBH you better address such questions to WebStorm support team directly, e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Are you running an X11 GUI environment?

Comment: Is it Fedora 27, or 29?

Answer (score 1):

Java.AWT library requires X11 GUI environment to work. Do you work on your Linux workstation directly, or access it remotely? Also, what JDK do you run WebStorm with? make sure that it has the graphical libraries included.
See also [this link for more info](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/can't-connect-to-x11-window-server-using-'-0-0'-as-the-value-of-the-display-variable-178234/)

Answer (score -2):

try this first:

```
$ chmod +x ./webstorm.sh
```

and then

```
$ ./webstorm.sh
```